# How to get the id of the added item after a post request in react?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, crud

I have a function which takes two inputs and makes a post request in react:

```
addNote(title, content){
    this.setState({title: title, content: content, error: ''}, () => {
        const newNote = {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newNote)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({error: 'Error adding note.'});
            console.error('Error during adding note', error);
        })
        const storedNotes = this.state.notes;
        storedNotes.unshift(newNote);
        this.setState({notes: storedNotes});
        //Adding this.fetchNotes(); here does not work
    });
}

fetchNotes(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({isLoading: false, notes: data}))
}
```

The id of the note is something like 5b0fac246637e1005ca0a7b5 (given by mongoose). How can I get the id of a newly added item in react so that I can do other operations like updating and deleting notes in the route /notes/:noteId? When I add a note and try to delete it, there is a 404 error since the id is undefined. On page reload, the operations work fine. I don't want to make a post request in the server since the view is rendered by react.

I tried a get request of all the notes again after adding the note. It does not work as intended. The added note does not show immediately on submit.

Should I make a post request with an id myself, say, new Date().toISOString()?

Comment: How would anyone know what to answer with unless you show the actual "server" side code which does the actual "adding" to the database? The front end really has nothing to do with this as all it does is asks the back end to do something. So you're showing us the wrong code.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, thank you so much. I added the line data => res.send(data) in the server and was able to get the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don you return the new mongoose id after your POST request?

something like this:

```
addNote(title, content){
    this.setState({title: title, content: content, error: ''}, () => {
        const newNote = {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newNote)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // here data.id might contain your objectId

            const storedNotes = this.state.notes;
            storedNotes.unshift(newNote);
            this.setState({notes: storedNotes});
            //Adding this.fetchNotes(); here does not work
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({error: 'Error adding note.'});
            console.error('Error during adding note', error);
        });
    });
}

fetchNotes(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({isLoading: false, notes: data}))
}
```

but this requires some refactoring of the your /notes endpoint on your server.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can get the id now!